# Read GET parameters using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, get

I would like to call Javascript in an HTML file like below:

```
<body>
<script src="./sample.js?ts=123456789&id=31ade2"></script>
</body>
```

How can I use `ts` and `id` in `sample.js`? Is this even possible?

I searched on Google, but what I found was to use `location.href`, which didn't return `ts` or `id`.

(Explanation why `window.location.href` doesn't solve this problem.)
Let's say the script above is in `example.com/index.html`. `window.location.href` in `sample.js` returns `example.com/index.html` but not `./sample.js?ts=123456789&id=31ade2`.

Comment: Those parameters go to the *server*; unless you make provisions there to inject them somehow, the script is not going to see them. But what's the *context*, why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Are you using node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think the easiest way to pass params to `sample.js` is to use variables. For example, I can set `window._values = {'ts': '123456789', 'id': '31ade2'};` and `sample.js` can read it. I simply thought using GET parameters was smarter.

Comment: @EdHeal I have never looked into node, so am not sure what it can do. This time I only put a static js file in Nginx server.

Comment: That doesn't give the context. Also it's not clear why the behaviour of href surprised you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I would like users (media) of our service to send us some sorts of data. The users are supposed to render the script with parameters on their webpages. I am actually a backend engineer, so do not know a lot about Javascript...

Comment: But if they're only needed on the client side, why force the round trip to the server? This is why I'm asking for context, currently you have a http://xyproblem.info

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess there are some confusions. We are collecting web data. Our clients are publishers who have their own websites. We ask publishers to put our script to their webpages. I wrote `src="./sample.js"` because I am now testing in my local environment, but the server where `sample.js` should be different from servers which return webpages. We have to ask publishers to make some variables available to our script.

Comment: This is going in circles, I'm not going to waste further time on it. [Edit] the question to clarify the context and spend some time thinking about whether your approach actually makes sense given your needs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am not sure why you write "if they're only needed on the client side, why force the round trip to the server?". I believe my approach (asking publishers to place scripts on their websites) is a common way to track users. Could you explain why you think the approach doesn't make sense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48354460/read-get-parameters-using-javascript#comment83696265_48354460

Answer (score 0):

Inside `sample.js` you need to get reference to the script element itself. Simple way to do it is by reading `document.scripts` collection:

```
const thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length - 1]
const params = getParams(thisScript.src)

console.log(params) // { ts: "123456789", id: "31ade2" }
```

<sub>* Note, in order for this to work as expected, script should not load asynchronously, or have defer/async attribute.</sub>

As for `getParams` function, feel free to use any implementation you like. For example good on from this post: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)